# iOS In-app purchase - unable to unlock the content as the function is in another view controller

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, in-app

I have set up an In-App purchase using a 'IAPHelper' class. I can retrieve the correct information from the App Store and display it in one VC. Once a user selects the required purchase item in that VC, the details are displayed on the next View Controller called 'Review'. This is where the actual purchase takes place. I have a 'buyProduct' function that is working fine in this ReviewVC, and sends the product payment to the paymentQueue of the SKPaymentTransactionObserver of the IAPHelper class. 
I need to unlock the content via a Pop Up in the 'Review VC' which should appear once the purchase status is shown as 'purchased' in the SKPaymentTransactionObserver, so I have tried many ways to include this function as part of the paymentQueue status for 'purchased' but the app always crashes after successful payment, once it reaches the function to show the PopUp.
Here's some code - I won't include all the IAPHelper code, just the relevant pieces:

```
open class IAPHelper: NSObject { ......
var review: ReviewVC! ...... }

extension IAPHelper: SKPaymentTransactionObserver {

    public func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
        for trans in transactions {
            print("func IAPHelper = \(trans.transactionState.status(), trans.payment.productIdentifier)")
            switch trans.transactionState {
            case .purchasing: break
            case .purchased: complete(transaction: trans)
                break
            case .failed : fail(transaction: trans)
            case .restored : restore(transaction: trans)
            case .deferred : break
           // default: queue.finishTransaction(trans)
            }
        }
    }

    func complete(transaction: SKPaymentTransaction) {
        deliverPurchaseNotificationFor(identifier: transaction.payment.productIdentifier)
        SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
        review.showSuccessPopUp() //***ERROR IS HERE***Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x10426ac70)*****

    }
```

This is the code in the ReviewVC file:-

```
class ReviewVC: UIViewController {
 @IBAction func buyTestButton(_ sender: Any) {
        print("Buy button pressed - products = \(products?.localizedTitle ?? "No Product")")
        buyProduct()
    }

    func buyProduct() {
        let payment = SKPayment(product: products!)
        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment as SKPayment)

    }


    //SUCCESSFUL PURCHASE:-
    func showSuccessPopUp() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4) {
            self.hideView.isHidden = false
        }
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.8) {
            self.successPopUp.isHidden = false
        }
    }
```

Been stuck on this for days so any help would be much appreciated!!

Comment: Are you saying it is crashing on `showSuccessPopUp()`? If that is the case, which line is crashing and what is the error? Also, I see `self.hideView` and `self.successPopUp` but I don't see the initialization for either. Without being provided the problem, it is difficult to provide a solution.

Comment: @impression7vx yes it crashes when the function is called within the 'complete' function. I have shown this in the code I included, where it says '**error is here**'. The self.hideview and self.successPopUp are IB outlets in the Review VC. As you can see, I am trying to call this showSuccessPopup function in the IAPHelper class, once the purchase has been made successfully. Let me know if you need further info - and thanks for any help.

Comment: Why are you calling it twice? Once in `paymentQueue()` and `complete()`? And on top of that what is there error? Is that all  error prints out or does it have a lot of mumble jumble? Preferred if you print out the whole mumble jumble

Comment: Sorry - typo calling it twice. That’s all the error says

Comment: How do you initialize `review` inside IAPHelper class?

Comment: I bet `review` is nil

Comment: Shown just under the class IAPHelper - var review: ReviewVC!

Comment: Yes you’re right - just ran it again and review is nil

Comment: Please upvote/accept answer so others can see what your problem was and potentially help out others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `review` is `nil`.

You are declaring it as a variable `var review: ReviewVC!` however, you are never initializing it.

Initialization is something like `review = Something`.

Not sure where your code is calling `IAP()` but wherever it is, I would do something like:

```
var iap = IAP()
iap.review = self //if you are in the review class.
```

Hard to tell as I am not sure where you declare your IAP object.